# how to change the name of the field in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to change the fieldname schedtimein into schedtimein plus the value of x.. example schedtimein1, schedtimein2 and so on...how can i do that, sorry im new here in so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var x =  1;


    $('#meetingForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            schedtimein: {
                verbose: false,
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The start time is required'
                    },

                    callback: {
                        message: 'The start time must be earlier then the end one',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            var schedtimeout = validator.getFieldElements('schedtimeout' + x).val();
                            if (schedtimeout === '') {
                                return true;
                            }
                            var startHour    = parseInt(value.split(':')[0], 10),
                                startMinutes = parseInt(value.split(':')[1], 10),
                                endHour      = parseInt(schedtimeout.split(':')[0], 10),
                                endMinutes   = parseInt(schedtimeout.split(':')[1], 10);

                            if (startHour < endHour || (startHour == endHour && startMinutes < endMinutes)) {
                                // The end time is also valid
                                // So, we need to update its status
                                validator.updateStatus('schedtimeout' + x, validator.STATUS_VALID, 'callback');
                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            schedtimeout: {
                verbose: false,
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The end time is required'
                    },

                    callback: {
                        message: 'The end time must be later then the start one',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            var schedtimein = validator.getFieldElements('schedtimein' + x).val();
                            if (schedtimein == '') {
                                return true;
                            }
                            var startHour    = parseInt(schedtimein.split(':')[0], 10),
                                startMinutes = parseInt(schedtimein.split(':')[1], 10),
                                endHour      = parseInt(value.split(':')[0], 10),
                                endMinutes   = parseInt(value.split(':')[1], 10);

                            if (endHour > startHour || (endHour == startHour && endMinutes > startMinutes)) {
                                // The start time is also valid
                                // So, we need to update its status
                                validator.updateStatus('schedtimein' + x, validator.STATUS_VALID, 'callback');
                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How to solve this? how to change the name of the field schedtimein in to schedtimein plus the value of x, like schedtimein1, schedtimein2 and ...

Comment: I can't fully understand about your purpose.Could you let your code more objective?

Comment: thanks for the reply sir, i have a multiple input tag with a name schedtimein1, schedtimein2, and so on.. i was running the javascript code in a while statement. i want to return a value on a specific input tag..

Comment: @Mohith P . thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define variable property names when delecearing object literals `var obj = {prop: value}`. But you can add them after defining the object like so...

```
var x = 1;
var fields = { // declare
    schedtimeout: { ... }
};

fields['schedtimein' + x] = { ... }; // will add schedtimein1 to fields object.
// ...Add as many as you like with different values of { ... } (different values).

$('#meetingForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: { ... },
    fields: fields // now add your final object here.
});
```

EDIT: As suggested by the commenter below, to implement your incrementally named properties, you would just loop over them like so...

```
for (; x <= numberOfProps; x++) {
    fields['schedtimein' + x] = makeMyObjectBasedOnX(x);
}
```

Where the `makeMyObjectBasedOnX` function returns an object based on the passed value of `x` and therefore unique to each new property you define.

Comment: It looks like the 'schedtimein + x' values are are the same - except for the value of x. I'd encapsulate it in a function and then call it like so: fields['schedtimein' + x] = getValueOfField(x);

Comment: @puqeko thanks to a fast reply sir.. i will try this, i will let you know if it work..thanks

Comment: @VishalBardoloi A very valid point. Thanks for the feedback. I've edited that into the answer – hope you don't mind. :)